# How to use Bluetooth to send audio on Windows IOT

Tags: audio, bluetooth, windows-iot

I am new to Bluetooth and I want to transmit my sound to my Bluetooth receiver. How is this done in Windows IOT? My App gives out the sound via aux right now, and I want it to use the bluetooth dongle. How do I set this up?

I would ask more precisely but as I already said, I don't actually know a lot about Bluetooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that my problem does not have a solution so far, because right now Windows IOT does not support the Audio Profile yet.
[click me](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/Bluetooth.htm)

Comment: That would explain it. Thanks for the update. I added an update to my answer to relate how my own testing went.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't gotten Bluetooth working on my RPi yet (still waiting for the adapter to arrive), but I would assume it would work similar to Bluetooth on "regular" Windows...you just need to pair with the audio device.

With other Windows devices I have, once paired, the audio is re-routed through the Bluetooth connection by default. I have used one of these [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B004VM1T5S](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004VM1T5S) to connect to my home stereo to my Surface Pro and that is how it worked.

Once I get my Bluetooth adapter for the RPi, I will try it with that as well.

You can configure the Bluetooth devices on the RPi by connecting your browser to `http://<yourPiNameOrIp>:8080/bluetooth.htm`

(or launch the browser through the WindowsIoTCoreWatcher and select the Bluetooth page)

The text on the page implies that just visiting that page will put the Pi in to pairing mode and it will start scanning for devices.

If you have already gotten that far, perhaps you can post more detail about what point your are stuck at.

Update: I received my BT adaptor and was able to get a set of Bluetooth headphones paired with the RPi. However I have been unable to output audio to the headphones yet. I wrote a quick test app just to play some system sounds, and it will play sounds to the audio jack, but not to the headphones. I suspect I have to switch the default audio device, but I haven't figured out how to do that yet. If I figure it out, I will update here again.

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth streaming now works with the latest update of IoT.

As of Windows IoT Build 17134 [(see link)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/release-notes/currentcommercial):

> "We've added support for the Bluetooth A2DP-SRC profile which allows a
>   device to act as an audio source for Bluetooth streaming, including
>   remote control capabilities over Bluetooth using the AVRCP profile."

Note that when streaming bluetooth audio and connected to lan via the onboard wifi there is a lot of choppyness [(see link)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/release-notes/currentcommercial)

As noted in the link above, a workaround is to buy an external wifi dongle that matches the compatible wifi hardware for IoT [(see link)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/hardwarecompatlist)

You should be able to disable the onboard wifi as seen here [(see link)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=182186)

Answer (score 0):

For whom it may concern. I followed [the advice given by user1609530](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38102/how-to-use-bluetooth-to-send-audio-on-windows-iot#answer-85354). I'm in Europe and ordered this dongle, [Ultra-Mini Bluetooth CSR 4.0 USB Dongle Adapter - Black](http://www.dx.com/p/ultra-mini-bluetooth-csr-4-0-usb-dongle-adapter-black-143276), which is absurdly cheap but works very well for my Raspberry pi/streaming/Bluetooth solution.